# How to calculate the number of characters in sentence of a text file?

Tags: python, character, nltk

I want to split a text into sentences and then print the number of characters of each sentence, but the program does not calculate the number of characters in each sentence.

I have tried to tokenize the file entered by the user into sentences and loop through the sentences counting and printing the number of characters in each. The code I've tried is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,wordpunct_tokenize
import re
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

while True:
    try:
        file_to_open =Path(input("\nYOU SELECTED OPTION 8: 
            CALCULATE SENTENCE LENGTH. Please, insert your file 
path: "))
        with open(file_to_open,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            words = sent_tokenize(f.read())
            break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nFile not found. Better try again")
    except IsADirectoryError:
        print("\nIncorrect Directory path.Try again")


print('\n\n This file contains',len(words),'sentences in total')



wordcounts = []
caracter_count=0
sent_number=1
with open(file_to_open) as f:
    text = f.read()
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    for sentence in sentences:
        if sentence.isspace() !=True:
            caracter_count = caracter_count + 1
            print("Sentence", sent_number,'contains',caracter_count, 
'characters')
            sent_number +=1
            caracter_count = caracter_count + 1
```

I WANT TO PRINT SOMETHING LIKE:

" SENTENCE 1 HAS 35 CHARACTERS"
" SENTENCE 2 HAS 45 CHARACTERS"

and so on....

The output that I'm getting with this program is:
This file contains 4 sentences in total
"Sentence 1 contains 0 characters"
"Sentence 2 contains 1 characters"
"Sentence 3 contains 2 characters"
"Sentence 4 contains 3 characters"

Anyone could help me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not counting the number of characters in your sentence with caracter_count. I think that changing your for loop into :

```
sentence_number = 1
for sentence in sentences:
    if not sentence.isspace():
        print("Sentence {} contains {} characters".format(sentence_number, len(sentence))
        sentence_number += 1
```

will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Well your question seems to be interesting, this problem has a simple solution. Remember for the first run use this command "nltk.download('punkt')" after first run just comment it out.

```
import nltk
#nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

def count_lines(file):
    count=0
    myfile=open(file,"r")
    string = ""

    for line in myfile:
        string+=line  
        print(string)

    number_of_sentences = sent_tokenize(string)

    for w in number_of_sentences:
        count+=1
        print("Sentence ",count,"has ",len(w),"words")

count_lines("D:\Atharva\demo.txt")
```

OUTPUT:

```
What is Python language?Python is a widely used high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic programming language. Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than possible in languages such as C++ or Java. Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles. It features a dynamic type system and automatic memory management and has a large and comprehensive standard library. The best way we learn anything is by practice and exercise questions. We  have started this section for those (beginner to intermediate) who are familiar with Python.  
Sentence  1 has  119 words
Sentence  2 has  175 words
Sentence  3 has  134 words
Sentence  4 has  117 words
Sentence  5 has  69 words
Sentence  6 has  95 words
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but I need the number of characters in the sentence, not the number of words.

Comment: actually its counting the no. of characters, the function len() gives the length of any value. When the program breaks the para into sentences it counts the no. of words using len() function.